# handle ui-view inside modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window in which I want to create different sub-views for tabs. As it is a modal, it doesn't have a URL. How do I handle the ui-views inside the modal for each tab. Do I need to have config file for it ?
Ideal structure:

```
div.modal-header
    h4.modal-title
        i.icon.icon-bell-outline
        | {{ config.title }}

div.modal-body(ng-if="vm.loading === 0")
    uib-tabset(active="active")
        uib-tab(index="0")
            tab-heading
                a.tab-head(ng-model="vm.selectedIncidentState", translate)
                    | Select an existing incident
            ui-view("sub-view")
        uib-tab(index="1")
            tab-heading
                tab-head
                    a.tab-head(ng-model="vm.selectedIncidentState", translate)
                        | Create a new incident
           ui-view(" ");
```

Modal Instance Controller:

```
function EscalateAlertModalInstanceController ($scope, logger, $uibModalInstance, modalConfig, alertsInfo) {
        logger.info("EscalateAlertModalInstanceController activated");
        $scope.modalConfig = modalConfig;
        $scope.alertsInfo = alertsInfo;
        /**
        * Called when the alert(s) are saved
        */
        $scope.onSave = function (error) {
            $uibModalInstance.close(error);
        };
        /**
        * Called when dialog is dismissed by clicking on cancel
        */
        $scope.onCancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
        };
    }
```

modal config:

```
vm.escalate = function () {
            var modalInstance;
            modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                backdrop: "static", // disables modal closing by click on the backdrop
                template: "<escalate-to-incident config=\"modalConfig\" alerts=\"alertsInfo\" on-save=\"onSave(error)\" on-cancel=\"onCancel()\"></escalate-to-incident>", // jscs:ignore maximumLineLength
                controller: "EscalateAlertModalInstanceController",
                size: "lg",
                resolve: {
                    /**
                     * modal config title
                     */
                    modalConfig: function () {
                        return {
                            title: gettextCatalog.getPlural(vm.selectedAlertsCount, "Escalate {{ count }} alert to an incident", "Escalate {{ count }} alerts to an incident", {count: vm.selectedAlertsCount}) // jscs:ignore maximumLineLength
                        };
                    },
                }
            });
```

Do i need to add the state in the modal config ? if yes can i not give URL ?
Please help

Comment: Are You using angular-bootstrap? If so, why not use angular-ui-tabs inside the modal?

Comment: yes i am using angular-bootstrap. and i am also using ui-tabs. but the tab content is huge. so i thought i would create a separate view for the view and call it from the html file.